# How would I seal the raw edges of particle board cabinets for protection against getting wet?

Tags: waterproofing, cabinets, particle-board

We are using IKEA cabinets for our kitchen. I've read that water is the enemy of particle board and will cause it to swell.

So I want to know if there is a preventative measure that I can take to seal the raw edges of the cabinets around the sink (basically the top edge of the base sink cabinet.)

Comment: @daniel is right-- PVA or any waterproof glue will work. A couple of coats of primer will also work well. Be sure to use lots of silicone between the sink and the counter to keep water from getting to the cut edge.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done this, but certainly I can think of occasions where I have seen this kind of water damage on particle board furniture in kitchens.

I would consider waterproofing it by using a glue that will form a plastic-like layer to cover the exposed edges. PVA will work and is cheap and easy to apply, but isn't very hard wearing. An epoxy resin is a tougher alternative.

A quick Google to back up my intuition gives me:

http://www.diydoctor.org.uk/projects/pvaadhesive.htm

Which states:

"Timber can be sealed with PVA to give it a waterproof quality, although if the surface of the timber is to be subject to any wear or traffic, then PVA, as it is an emulsion, will eventually fail."